# If $(X_k)$ is i.i.d. and $E(X_1)>0$ then $\frac{1}{N\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{k=1}^iX_k\to\infty$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

> If $Y_i=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}X_k$ where the random variables $X_k$ are independent identically distributed, with mean $0<\mu<\infty$, then how can we prove that
>   $$S_N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{Y_i}{N}$$ converges in probability to $\infty$ as $N\to\infty$?

I guess I should use CLT or WLLN to prove that but I was not able to do so. Any idea? I also could not use the Kolmogorov's Three-Series Theorem.

Comment: ... tends to infinity as $N$ tends to infinity or what do you mean? Also, must $\mu$ be positive?

Comment: @Lovsovs Thanks for your comment. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What about showing convergence in mean, and then deducing convergence in probability?

Comment: @Hetebrij Convergence in mean to infinity? How is that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: There are $N(N+1)/2$ elements in the partial sum, i.e. of order $N^2$ and the sum is divided by only $N^{3/2}$.

Comment: @Susan20200 Did you try to compute the expectation and the variance of each $S_N$? Why not?

Comment: @Did As I see, the existence of variance is not supposed.

Comment: @NCh I know. And this should not prevent the OP to first look at this case.